# Why isn't this code finding the length of the longest string in my set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I encountered a very weird set iterator issue in C++.

```
set<string> dict;
dict.insert("hello");
dict.insert("my");

int maxLen = INT_MIN;

set<string>::iterator itr;
for (itr=dict.begin(); itr!=dict.end(); itr++) {
    int len = (*itr).length();
    if ( len > maxLen )
        maxLen = (*itr).length();
}
```

This code help me set maxLen to 5, which is the length of the longest word in the word set.

```
set<string> dict;
dict.insert("hello");
dict.insert("my");

int maxLen = INT_MIN;

set<string>::iterator itr;
for (itr=dict.begin(); itr!=dict.end(); itr++) {
    if ( (*itr).length() > maxLen )
        maxLen = (*itr).length();
}
```

However, this code cannot give me correct result. After I run the code, the maxLen remains the value of INT_MIN. Basically nothing changes except that I don't use a variable to hold the value of (*itr).length() any more.

This is very weird to me. Am I missing something? I just want to clarify my doubts about iterator usage.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless this is something like homework where you need to do the work on your own, you probably want to use `int maxlen=std::max_element(dict.begin(), dict.end(), [](std::string const &s) { return s.length(); });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the `string::length` function returns an *unsigned* type while the `int` type you're using is *signed*. In a comparison between signed and unsigned values, the signed value is always converted to an unsigned value first. In your case, the conversion of `INT_MIN` to an unsigned value makes it take on the maximum possible unsigned value, because the bit patterns for `INT_MIN` and `UINT_MAX` are the same.

The reason this works the first time around is that the unsigned values were cast to `int`s when being assigned to the temporary variable.

To fix this, add a cast back in:

```
for (itr=dict.begin(); itr!=dict.end(); itr++) {
    if ( int((*itr).length()) > maxLen )
        maxLen = (*itr).length();
}
```

As long as you're at it, there are a lot of other stylistic fixes you could do here, such as

- switching postincrement `++` to preincrement `++` for efficiency,
- using `->` instead of `(*).`,
- adding whitespace around operators, and
- declaring the iterator locally in the loop

This is shown here:

```
for (set<string>::iterator itr = dict.begin(); itr != dict.end(); ++itr) {
    if (int(itr->length()) > maxLen) {
       maxLen = itr->length();
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, if you have a C++11-compliant compiler, using a range-based for loop:

```
for (const auto& val: dict) {
    if (int(val.length()) > maxLen) {
       maxLen = val.length();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As long as you're going for style changes, you might as well suggest replacing INT_MIN with std::numeric_limits<int>::min()

Comment: Hi templatetypedef, thank you for your neat and clean clarification! I got it. This is quite a important note to me that I need to pay attention to the details of C++ language mechanism. I have a following question. If this is the case, how would you recommend me to do comparison? Do you think it's a good idea to always convert the two numbers I am comparing to int?

Comment: @user1582802- If you know for a fact that the set isn't empty, make `maxLen` a variable of type `string::size_type` and set it to 0. It will get updated to the correct initial value on the first loop iteration with no casting required.

Comment: And also thanks for your style advices. Very useful! I really appreciate your advices!

Comment: Do you ibject to undefined or unspecified behavior?  Converting an out of bounds `unsigned` to `int` generates an unsoecified `int` iirc.  So if your strings are long, the above could bahave surprisingly.  The length required is a bit ridiculous, mind you, so this is not a practical problem.